# Corda Service not running locally

Tags: corda

I have made a CustomvaultQuery.Service class for getting details from database to use it in flow, but in logs it is showing IllegalArgument as CustomvaultQuery$Service is not found in Corda as @CordaService

Comment: Kindly attach also the error logs so we can help you.

Comment: Please also paste the definition of `CustomvaultQuery$Service`.

Comment: Without error logs, I can't be sure but sometimes the problem happens when a new class is created and not nodes are not  redeployed (meaning the nodes still use the outdated CorDapp). Redeploying will distribute new CorDapp with the new class.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look the following example on Corda Service code:

```
private fun directPayment() {
    val ourIdentity = ourIdentity()
    serviceHub.vaultService.trackBy<PaymentRequestState>().updates.subscribe {
        update: Vault.Update<PaymentRequestState> -> update.produced.forEach{
        message: StateAndRef<PaymentRequestState> ->
            val state = message.state
            if (ourIdentity == serviceHub.networkMapCache.getPeerByLegalName(CordaX500Name("BankOperator", "Toronto", "CA"))!!) {
                executor.execute {
                    log.info("Directing to message $state")
                    serviceHub.startFlow(PaymentFlowInitiator())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is exactly doing what you are looking for, a database query service. 
Full code at: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Features/cordaService-autopayroll/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/autopayroll/flows/AutoPaymentService.kt